# DNS is different for domain when http:// is used

Tags: domain-name-system, http

I'm using the Linux tool dig to see the DNS records for my website.
When I type in

`dig www.aaaaaaa.com`

it returns one IP address and when I get one IP and when I type in

`dig http://www.aaaaaaa.com`

it gives me a different IP.

Why would http:// make a different to the DNS record being returned?

I should mention I'm using AWS Route53 so that US IP addresses go to a US server and other IP addresses go to the main server.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please show us the output of the second dig command.

Comment: Don't prefix `http://` that's the protocol not your domain and those characters are invalid in DNS.

Answer (score 4):

This could be possible if you setup a wildcard DNS record like:

```
*.aaaaaaa.com IN A 1.2.3.4
```

And configured a different record for `www.aaaaaaa.com`.

Needless to say, you shouldn't add `http://` to the DNS query since this is not part of the hostname.
No normal client would do that.

Comment: Most likely. `http://www` is the label being looked up within the domain, as opposed to `www`.

Answer (score 3):

Hostnames with a `http://` prefix are illegal, as are all hostnames with a protocol prefix.  Most resolvers would return NXDOMAIN in this case, however, many ISPs and others return their own IPs in place of NXDOMAIN responses such as OpenDNS:

```
$ host http://www.aaaaaaa.com 208.67.222.222
Using domain server:
Name: 208.67.222.222
Address: 208.67.222.222#53
Aliases: 

http://www.aaaaaaa.com has address 67.215.65.132
Host http://www.aaaaaaa.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

See how it says "http://www.aaaaaaa.com has address 67.215.65.132" -- that's a lie.  That IP goes to OpenDNS' landing page where they show you ads.

Comment: You might want to read RFC1912 2.1...there is a vast difference between what characters are legal in a label, what legalities are required to be enforced by implementations, and what characters are illegal for a *hostname* (which is different than legal for DNS). This label passes the first two tests, and only fails the third.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question. I too saw what they report and whilst it may not be legal it was returning an address. The address was (for me) the same as the A record.

Answer (score 2):

I did see the behaviour you describe but it looks like whatever was causing this to happen has been 'fixed' as

```
 dig  http://www.ecanvasser.com
```

now (correctly) returns NXDOMAIN.

FWIW I had the same IP address returned for both (I'm in the UK and was directed to ie...).

---

My initial thoughts (which are moot now) were that it was being handled as a wildcard entry but the `:` and `/` aren't valid characters for hostnames so whatever it was, was going an extra mile to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are getting a responce

I may be mistaken but dig command is used in this way, **without http:// or www.**

```
#dig google.com

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-2-Ubuntu <<>> google.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 63957
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 11, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;google.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.65
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.66
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.67
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.68
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.69
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.70
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.71
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.72
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.73
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.78
google.com.     254 IN  A   173.194.113.64

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
google.com.     53642   IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     53642   IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     53642   IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
google.com.     53642   IN  NS  ns2.google.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.google.com.     226442  IN  A   216.239.32.10
ns2.google.com.     226442  IN  A   216.239.34.10
ns3.google.com.     226666  IN  A   216.239.36.10
ns4.google.com.     226666  IN  A   216.239.38.10

;; Query time: 14 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.1.1#53(127.0.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Mar 23 18:55:55 EET 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 351
```

Comment: http// for sure but www.example.com and example.com could easily be different machines.

Comment: yea thats true one is website and the other could be DNS or a mail server, or maybe i'm wrong :)